# How to change vue data from outside?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nativescript-vue

I have a function outside of `export default` object. How can I make Stop button to change into play button after 1 second?

**In Short:** I want to change `playingStatus` into `false` out of scope.

---

### **Please check [{N} PlayGround link for question](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=SLVQeY&v=8)**

---

```html
<template>
    <Page>
        <ActionBar title="Home" />
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
                <Image v-show="!playingStatus" @tap="startFunc"
                    src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconic-1/32/play_alt-512.png"
                    stretch="aspectFit" />
                <Image v-show="playingStatus"
                    src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/eightyshades/512/24_Stop-512.png"
                    stretch="aspectFit" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    function playForAWhile() {
        setTimeout(stop, 1000);
    }

    function stop() {
        playingStatus =
        false; // scope error... How to change vue data from outside?
    }

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                playingStatus: false
            };
        },
        methods: {
            startFunc() {
                this.playingStatus = true;
                playForAWhile();
            }
        }
    };
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Or instead of changing variable from outside, how can I toggle images without vue object.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mate the function a method of this component. This way you can manipulate its data ;)

Comment: Do you mean '''stop''' function?

Comment: Yes, exactly why would you need it outside the component ? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Now **Stop** is not defined. https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=SLVQeY&v=9 
I think there must be a way to bridge between vue object and script part.

Comment: Where do you call stop ?

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=SLVQeY&v=9

Comment: Okay I see what you did there, I will show you the way in the answer

Comment: Method.call(this: vue, ...arcs)

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Element-amp-Component-Access